# What is the difference between shuffle and permute

Tags: x86, intel, simd, naming, avx

In x86-64 SIMD instruction names, as well as the [intrinsic](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=94,5196,3343,3339,3330,3295,2428,2426,4172,525,618,4167,4173,4172,4174,4201,433,4201,4906,4962,5497,4179,4202,5276,5306,433,4174,5199,533,4174,4174,3170,4179,4155,5143&text=shuffle&techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2) functions you can use to access them from C/C++, you find both the terms *shuffle* (e.g., `_mm_shuffle_epi32`) and *permute* (e.g., `_mm_permute_pd`).

Superficially, they seem to both be used for data movement stuff. What's the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't looked for inspiration outside of x86.  I don't think there's any standard convention here.

---

**I think they just switched from "shuffle" to "permute" at some point in time** between SSSE3 `pshufb` and AVX1 `vpermilps/pd` / `vperm2f128`.  Everything before AVX is called "shuffle", everything after is called "permute".

(SSE4.x didn't introduce any instructions named "shuffle" or "permute", just `pinsrd` / `pextrd` and other operand sizes being the main shuffles that SSE4.1 added)

---

**There are 2 exceptions to that**, not counting VEX / EVEX encodings of `vshufps`, `vpshufd`, etc.:

[AVX512F **`VSHUFF32X4`**](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vshuff32x4:vshuff64x2:vshufi32x4:vshufi64x2) (and 64x2 and integer versions) 128-bit granularity lane shuffles with immediate control **have the same design as `vshufps`**: low half of the destination selects elements from the first source, high half selects from the 2nd source.  e.g. `_mm512_shuffle_i64x2(__m512i a, __m512i b, int imm);`
 **This naming is helpful to remember how the shuffle control works.**  With 4 output lanes, there's only room for 4x 2-bit selectors, not 4x 3-bit.  The 256-bit operand-size version still has the same limitation so it only uses the low 2 bits of the immediate, like `shufpd`.

[AVX512BITALG **`VPSHUFBITQMB`**](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VPSHUFBITQMB) is like [`vpmultishiftqb`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VPMULTISHIFTQB) (parallel bitfield extract) + vector->mask (like a movemask).  So it can select any 8 bits within each qword chunk of the input.

AVX512 256-bit granularity operations currently only exist with names like VEXTRACTF32x8 and VINSERTF32x8, not shuf or perm.

---

Intrinsic name do match instruction mnemonics as far as shuffle vs. permute, but otherwise can leave out "in lane" when the mnemonic has it, requiring the lane-crossing version to be different too.  (e.g. AVX1 [`vpermilps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermilps) = `_mm_permute_ps` imm8 or `_mm_permutevar_ps` __m128i control vs. AVX2 [`vpermps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermps) = `_mm256_permutexvar_ps`; not available with immediate control, but vpermpd is.

Intel's intrinsics guide only lists `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` for `vpermps`, while the ISA ref manual only lists `permutexvar`.  I assume most compilers support the older `permutexvar` name.  Anyway, weird choice, 8x32 sounds like an AVX512 instruction (with per-element masking); and maybe that's where that new intrinsic name came from.

---

There are no other pattern I've noticed.  **We can easily rule out all of the following hypotheses**:

- copy-and-shuffle (`pshufd xmm, xmm/mem, imm`) vs. in-place shuffle (`pshufb data, idx` or `shufps xmm, xmm, imm`)
- immediate control vs. variable-control (pshufd vs. pshufb  or AVX2 vpermd vs. vperm2i128)
- integer vs. FP (SSE2 pshufd vs. shufps/pd ; AVX2 vpermps vs. vpermd)
- 1-source vs. 2-source (pshufd vs. shufps ; AVX2 vpermd vs. AVX512 vpermt2d)
- lane-crossing vs. in-lane (AVX1 `vpermilps` vs. AVX2 `vpermps`)

The shuffle-control immediate works the same way in `pshufd` and `vpermq`-immediate. But unlike the "tricky" `vshuff32x4` case, both `pshufd` and `vpermq` work the obvious way so no need to make an analogy to another mnemonic.  Also, **"pshuf" is a bit awkward vs. "shuf" or "perm", so I can see why they'd want something else for packed-integer.**

Note that the "shuf" names go all the way back to SSE1 `shufps`, introduced by Pentium III (Katmai) at the same time as MMX2 `pshufw mm, mm, imm8`.

P5 Pentium MMX didn't have any instructions named shuf/perm instructions, just the `punpckl/h` shuffles in various sizes.

https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdocb.html#section-B.1.7 (That NASM appendix is helpful because it sorts mnemonics into groups by order of introduction.  It's what got me to notice the `vshuff32x4` mnemonic down in the AVX512 stuff after I thought they'd switched to calling everything "perm".)

Comment: Excellent answer. `_mm256_permutexvar_ps` seems to be missing from the intrinsics guide?

Comment: @BeeOnRope: It's in the ISA ref.  The intrinsics guide only lists `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` for `vpermps` and `_mm256_permute4x64_pd` for `vpermpd`.  Intel really went off the deep end there, making up names that sound like AVX512 where per-element masking matters.  I didn't check which compilers support which name.  I've run into this before but I forget what I found then.